# Coming up with a question, while trying to answer another one

Tags: discussion

Let's assume a user tries to find an answer for a question posed by another user. After a while, he addresses the question posed but he bumps into a new issue stemming from the solution he found. What is he supposed to do? Post the answer, explaining the issues coming up or post a new question that uses almost the same MWE but focuses on the new issue?

Comment: I would say post the answer with a note about the new issue and then post a new question, with a link to the old one, focused on the new issue.

Comment: What @CarLaTeX says, but additionally, you might want to put a "forward" link in your answer or a comment as well, stating that this particular issue is addressed there.

Comment: Anything that is worth being a question can be asked. I'd say you can even answer Q1 by a reduction to Q2, ask Q2, and cross-link Q1 and Q2. People will be fine as long as you are being clear, and not asking a question whose answer will help you win a bounty.